# Enable BinLogs on read-replica with binlog_format="row"

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, mysqlbinlog, debezium

I recently enabled binlogs on my read-replica by enabling automatic backups(As mentioned [here](https://blog.pythian.com/enabling-binary-logging-rds-read-replica/)). However the default binlog_format was set to MIXED.

```
binlog_format=MIXED
```

Because of this inconsistency the Debezium connector fails since it finds initial binlogs in MIXED format. Is there a way to enable binlogs with ROW format from the very beginning?

Adding Error log:

```
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: Caused by: io.debezium.text.ParsingException: Failed to parse statement 'update user_payments set address='400001', amount_details='{base:100.00, tax_1:0.00, tax_2:0.00, tax_3:0.00
}', bank_reference_number='698774', commercial_pack='HSPremiumMonth', country='in', coupon=null, create_date='2018-10-12 08:35:27', currency='INR', customer_id='acn|9a3722ef-5547-4e0e-ad3f-ef40eabf095e@mandardeodhar.me', discount_amount=0
.0, email='9a3722ef-5547-4e0e-ad3f-ef40eabf095e@mandardeodhar.me', fname='Vibhor', freetrial=1, hs_invoice_number=null, invoice_amount=199.0, invoice_date=null, invoice_number=null, last_update_date='2018-10-12 08:35:43', lname='User', me
ta=null, parent_transaction_id=null, payment_hash='2HL5LM', pg_commercial_pack='hotstar-razor-upi-hsp-month', pg_name='payu', pg_transaction_id='403993715518439176', service_configuration_mci=18, service_end_date='2018-11-11 08:35:43', se
rvice_start_date='2018-10-12 08:35:43', service_type='RECURRING', settlement_group=null, subscription_family_name='HotstarPremium', tax_amount=0.0, transaction_amount=199.0, transaction_status='Completed', transaction_type='Payment' where
 transaction_id=1012005'
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.relational.ddl.LegacyDdlParser.parse(LegacyDdlParser.java:225)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.relational.ddl.LegacyDdlParser.parse(LegacyDdlParser.java:200)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlSchema.applyDdl(MySqlSchema.java:297)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleQueryEvent(BinlogReader.java:637)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:436)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011... 7 more
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: Caused by: io.debezium.text.ParsingException: Expecting token type 128 at line 1, column 1 but found 'update':  ===>> update user_payments
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.text.TokenStream.consume(TokenStream.java:750)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.relational.ddl.LegacyDdlParser.consumeStatement(LegacyDdlParser.java:462)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.relational.ddl.LegacyDdlParser.parseUnknownStatement(LegacyDdlParser.java:309)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlDdlParser.parseNextStatement(MySqlDdlParser.java:191)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.relational.ddl.LegacyDdlParser.parse(LegacyDdlParser.java:219)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011... 11 more
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: [2018-10-12 08:35:43,348] INFO Error processing binlog event, and propagating to Kafka Connect so it stops this connector. Future binlog events read before connector is shutdown will be ignored. (io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader:457)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: [2018-10-12 08:35:43,517] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=um-users-qa-test-7-0} Committing offsets (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:328)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: [2018-10-12 08:35:43,517] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=um-users-qa-test-7-0} flushing 0 outstanding messages for offset commit (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:345)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: [2018-10-12 08:35:43,518] INFO WorkerSourceTask{id=um-users-qa-test-7-0} Finished commitOffsets successfully in 1 ms (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSourceTask:427)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: [2018-10-12 08:35:43,518] ERROR WorkerSourceTask{id=um-users-qa-test-7-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Failed to parse statement 'update user_payments set address='400001', amount_details='{base:100.00, tax_1:0.00, tax_2:0.00, tax_3:0.00}', bank_reference_number='698774', commercial_pack='HSPremiumMonth', country='in', coupon=null, create_date='2018-10-12 08:35:27', currency='INR', customer_id='acn|9a3722ef-5547-4e0e-ad3f-ef40eabf095e@mandardeodhar.me', discount_amount=0.0, email='9a3722ef-5547-4e0e-ad3f-ef40eabf095e@mandardeodhar.me', fname='Vibhor', freetrial=1, hs_invoice_number=null, invoice_amount=199.0, invoice_date=null, invoice_number=null, last_update_date='2018-10-12 08:35:43', lname='User', meta=null, parent_transaction_id=null, payment_hash='2HL5LM', pg_commercial_pack='hotstar-razor-upi-hsp-month', pg_name='payu', pg_transaction_id='403993715518439176', service_configuration_mci=18, service_end_date='2018-11-11 08:35:43', service_start_date='2018-10-12 08:35:43', service_type='RECURRING', settlement_group=null, subscription_family_name='HotstarPremium', tax_amount=0.0, transaction_amount=199.0, transaction_status='Completed', transaction_type='Payment' where transaction_id=1012005'
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.wrap(AbstractReader.java:200)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.AbstractReader.failed(AbstractReader.java:178)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.BinlogReader.handleEvent(BinlogReader.java:452)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.EventBuffer.completeTransaction(EventBuffer.java:187)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at io.debezium.connector.mysql.EventBuffer.add(EventBuffer.java:101)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.notifyEventListeners(BinaryLogClient.java:1055)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.listenForEventPackets(BinaryLogClient.java:913)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient.connect(BinaryLogClient.java:559)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at com.github.shyiko.mysql.binlog.BinaryLogClient$7.run(BinaryLogClient.java:793)
Oct 12 08:35:43 kafkaConnect1 connect-distributed[13342]: #011at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: I'm surprised that Debezium is stumbling upon the old binlog entries, assuming you're setting up the connector only after switching to ROW. It should start with a snapshot and then read the binlog beginning from "now". What snapshotting mode are you using?

Comment: I'm using "snapshot.mode":"initial"

Comment: Hum, strange. The only thing I can think of is that it's still using MIXED for some reason.

Comment: There isn't a way to retroactively change the binlogs that have already been created.  You verified that `SELECT @@BINLOG_FORMAT` does now return the expected value `ROW`?  Note also that RDS purges binlogs very quickly, so you should not even have any old logs, unless you [changed the retention time](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/mysql_rds_set_configuration.html) -- which you may want to do, to avoid log loss if your connector fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you enable the backup you can change the parameter group `binlog_format` to `ROW` in RDS.

**Select RDS product -> Select your instance.**

**Click in the Parameter group of your instance:**

[image]

**Search for the parameter `binlog_format` -> Select it -> Edit Parameters -> Select `Row`.**

[image]

After you do this, you will need to restart your instance to apply this new parameter value. After your database is back online again, you can check if the values are correct running these commands:

```
show global variables like 'log_bin';
show global variables like 'binlog_format';
```

The result should be something like this:
[image]

Then you can delete you connector using the [REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/references/restapi.html#delete--connectors-(string-name)-) from Kafka Connect and register your connector again with `"snapshot.mode": "when_needed"`. This will produce all rows from your tables in whitelist configuration to respective topics in Kafka.

Also, as Michael said, you may wanna increase the `binlog retention hours` parameter.

```
CALL mysql.rds_show_configuration;
CALL mysql.rds_set_configuration('binlog retention hours', 24);
```

I hope it helps.